# How create Far instead of Near in CATIA in VB or VBA

Tags: vb.net, macros, catia

I am writing small macro in VB.NET for CATIA and I am unable to create Far.

```vb
                ' Create a point
                Dim hybridShapePointCoord1 As HybridShapePointCoord = hybridShapeFactory1.AddNewPointCoord(0#, 0#, 10.0#)
                hybridBody1.AppendHybridShape(hybridShapePointCoord1)
                part.InWorkObject = hybridShapePointCoord1
                part.Update()

                ' Create a line
                Dim referencePoint1 As Reference = part.CreateReferenceFromObject(hybridShapePointCoord1)
                Dim hybridShapeDirection1 As HybridShapeDirection = hybridShapeFactory1.AddNewDirectionByCoord(0#, 0#, 1.0#)
                Dim hybridShapeLinePtDir1 As HybridShapeLinePtDir = hybridShapeFactory1.AddNewLinePtDir(referencePoint1, hybridShapeDirection1, -100.0#, 100.0#, False)
                hybridBody1.AppendHybridShape(hybridShapeLinePtDir1)
                part.InWorkObject = hybridShapeLinePtDir1
                part.Update()

                ' Create an intersection
                Dim referenceLine As Reference = part.CreateReferenceFromObject(hybridShapeLinePtDir1)
                Dim referenceBody As Reference = part.CreateReferenceFromObject(body)
                Dim hybridShapeIntersection1 As HybridShapeIntersection = hybridShapeFactory1.AddNewIntersection(referenceLine, referenceBody)
                hybridShapeIntersection1.PointType = 0 ' Adjust as needed
                hybridBody1.AppendHybridShape(hybridShapeIntersection1)
                part.InWorkObject = hybridShapeIntersection1
                part.Update()

                ' Create Near Points
                Dim referenceIntersection As Reference
                referenceIntersection = part.CreateReferenceFromObject(hybridShapeIntersection1)

                Dim hybridShapeNear1 As HybridShapeNear
                hybridShapeNear1 = hybridShapeFactory1.AddNewNear(referenceIntersection, referencePoint1)

                hybridBody1.AppendHybridShape(hybridShapeNear1)

                Dim hybridShapeNear2 As HybridShapeNear
                hybridShapeNear2 = hybridShapeFactory1.AddNewNear(referenceIntersection, referencePoint1)

                hybridBody1.AppendHybridShape(hybridShapeNear2)
```

I tried to record macro but it record it as creation of near anyway. Even in documentation is mentioned only Near, AddNewNear, but Far alternatives seems to be non existent.

I even tried to record changing Near to Far, but it just create another near:

```vb
Sub CATMain()

Dim partDocument1 As PartDocument
Set partDocument1 = CATIA.ActiveDocument

Dim part1 As Part
Set part1 = partDocument1.Part

Dim hybridShapeFactory1 As HybridShapeFactory
Set hybridShapeFactory1 = part1.HybridShapeFactory

Dim hybridBodies1 As HybridBodies
Set hybridBodies1 = part1.HybridBodies

Dim hybridBody1 As HybridBody
Set hybridBody1 = hybridBodies1.Item("Some Geoset")

Dim hybridShapes1 As HybridShapes
Set hybridShapes1 = hybridBody1.HybridShapes

Dim hybridShapeIntersection1 As HybridShapeIntersection
Set hybridShapeIntersection1 = hybridShapes1.Item("Intersect.1")

Dim reference1 As Reference
Set reference1 = part1.CreateReferenceFromObject(hybridShapeIntersection1)

Dim hybridShapePointCoord1 As HybridShapePointCoord
Set hybridShapePointCoord1 = hybridShapes1.Item("Point.13")

Dim reference2 As Reference
Set reference2 = part1.CreateReferenceFromObject(hybridShapePointCoord1)

Dim hybridShapeNear1 As HybridShapeNear
Set hybridShapeNear1 = hybridShapeFactory1.AddNewNear(reference1, reference2)

hybridBody1.AppendHybridShape hybridShapeNear1

part1.InWorkObject = hybridShapeNear1

part1.Update

Set partDocument1 = CATIA.ActiveDocument

partDocument1.Save

End Sub
```

Comment: Does the _HybridShapeNear_ has a option (see documentation) to switch to _far_?

Comment: @Shrotter As far as I know there are only 2 parameters by as mentioned in the catiadoc:
Func AddNewNear( Reference MultiElement, Reference ReferenceElement) As HybridShapeNear
What other option did you have in mind?

Comment: It was only i guess that they have added a parameter/option to switch to far (I've got only access to older documentations now). From the GUI it looks like, Dassault has extend the near feature.

Comment: There is no VB API for this. But there is a (somewhat recently added) EKL "far" function.  With the EKL function you can start with a datum/isolated point and use a formula to set its value to desired result. 

Formulas and datum geometry can all be created using the VB API. 

We implemented our own far function for VB using CAA years ago. If the far EKL function had existed at the time we probably wouldn't have had to.

Comment: @CRJohnson that's exactly what I was worried about... I used 2 points, each shifted in a different direction and one near to each. Next time I will try to use extremum.
Thanks for your information.

Answer (score 1):

This illustrates how you can use a formula to create a far feature using VB.NET.

```
'get the inputs and working geo set
Dim oPart As Part = oCATIA.ActiveDocument.part
Dim oGS  = oPart.HybridBodies.Item("Geometrical Set.1")
Dim oIntersect As HybridShape = oGS.HybridShapes.Item("Intersect.1")
Dim oFarPoint As HybridShape = oGS.HybridShapes.Item("Point.3")

'make a datum to assign the formula to
Dim oHSF As HybridShapeFactory = Part.HybridShapeFactory
Dim oDatum As AnyObject = oHSF.AddNewPointDatum(oPart.CreateReferenceFromObject(oFarPoint))
oGS.AppendHybridShape(oDatum)
oDatum.Name = "Far_Result"
oPart.UpdateObject(oDatum)

'create a formula
Dim oFX As Formula = 
oPart.Relations.CreateFormula(
"FAR_FORMULA",
"",
oDatum,
"far(" & oPart.Parameters.GetNameToUseInRelation(oIntersect ) & "," & oPart.Parameters.GetNameToUseInRelation(oFarPoint) & ")"
)
oPart.Update()
```